# Using UI-Router without defining urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

[Link](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/CvnxL)

I have a codepen example where I'm routing view inside a side menu (drag right to open it up) and changing view to create a pseudo sub-menu navigation.

Here's an example state provider from the codepen

```
.state('tabs.facts', {
  url: "/facts",
  views: {
    'home-tab': {
      templateUrl: "facts.html"
    }
  }
})
```

What I'm wondering is if the urls can be removed and still work. I've tried and haven't had any luck and waned to know if anyone who knew UI-Router knew if there was to set up state that didn't need any urls. Any ideas or help is appreciated.

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but I've defined abstract states (say "tabs") which has a url "/facts". Then the child states "tabs.facts", "tabs.whatever" do not need a URL.

Comment: I just attempted this in the codepen above and wasn't able to get it to work. I attempts to go to the next state but ends up just staying in the first state